# Is it possible to define a parameter before action in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

The question is as simple as the title.

Is it possible to have a route that looks like this: `{controller}/{id}/{action}`?

This is what I have in code right now (just a simple function) (`device` is my controller):

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Device/{id}/IsValid")]
public bool IsValid(int id) {
    return true;
}
```

But when I go to the following URL the browser says it can't find the page: `localhost/device/2/IsValid`.

And when I try this URL, it works just fine: `localhost/device/IsValid/2`

So, is it possible to use `localhost/device/2/IsValid` instead of the default route `localhost/device/IsValid/2`? And how to do this?

Feel free to ask more information! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to change codein RouteConfig file.
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{id}/{action}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

Comment: @RahulChavan What is `th`? And where do I have to add it?

Comment: RouteConfig file in App_start

Comment: Is this for web api or plain mvc

Comment: It can be used for WebAPI as well

Comment: Why do you need an action which returns a bool value?

Comment: @PavelYermalovich "(just a simple function)" - M Zeinstra, 2016

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Attribute routing. Make sure you enable attribute routing.

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

For MVC **RouteConfig.cs**

```
public class RouteConfig {

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        //...Other code removed for brevity
    }
}
```

In controller

```
[RoutePrefix("device")]
public class DeviceController : Controller {
    //GET device/2/isvalid
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}/IsValid")]
    public bool IsValid(int id) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! :D But, why "`:int`"? Why should I do that?

Comment: Its a constraint based on your sample. It could just as easily been `bool` or `long`. It's in case you want to make sure types used in the url conforms to the type you want. You don't have to do it. Read the referenced article.

Answer (score 2):

try using this before `Default` route in `RoutingConfig`

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "RouteName",
    "{controller}/{id}/{action}"
    );
```